# How to ask for an exit interview

Tags: exit-interview, exit-planning

I like the company I work for, I really do.
For specific reasons I am not willing to write here, though, I might have to go to work for another company. Provided that I work in an environment, where some data protection policies are enforced, I might have to leave the place the day I submit my resignations.

I would like HR to hear my voice though, and really understand what the strenghts and weaknesses of this company are. It is dumb / not beneficial / possible at all to ask for an exit interview, if I am not invited to have one?

I don't want to waste HR's time and I don't want to sound like the traitor trying to teach a lesson.

Comment: I just found out the following question as well: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/60475/how-do-exit-interviews-benefit-the-company . What a sad world we live in :/

Comment: @Noldor130884 If the company were willing to listen to your concerns *and act on them*, they already would be. All an exit interview will do is potentially burn bridges without any kind of benefit to you.

Comment: @Kaz Well not really. I am indeed the last HR would give voice to, and I thought in an event of a resignation, they'd be at least receptive.

Comment: Move on.  Not your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I say my reasons for leaving without being/sounding rude and without burning any bridges?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95441/how-do-i-say-my-reasons-for-leaving-without-being-sounding-rude-and-without-burn)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much should I say in an exit interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14921/how-much-should-i-say-in-an-exit-interview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like HR to hear my voice though, and really understand what
>   the strenghts and weaknesses of this company are. It is dumb / not
>   beneficial / possible at all to ask for an exit interview, if I am not
>   invited to have one?

Most companies who are of at least of a moderate maturity level will have an exit interview as part of their "employee departure" process.  If you really are interested in your voice being heard, you also need to consider *what you hope to achieve* by participating in an exit interview.

If your feedback is only going to equate to a *polite bitch session*, you are wasting your time.  If however you have **fact based** feedback that would be valuable to the company, then by all means ask for the exit interview.

Even if, for whatever reason, you are not granted one you could still send a farewell email to the appropriate parties with your feedback, and let them process it as they see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Just ask for an appointment to discuss "the future of your career". Talk about your leaving-plans and the reasoning there. Have your written resignation ready to hand over afterwards.